# Better more efficient option (sum of vlookup + multiplication)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wrote a formula in excel to do a calculation with a lookup and then calculate the sum of the results. The formula is very bulky and there should be a better option. any options?

The furmula now is :

```
0.001*SUM((H4*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,PARTMAS,6,0),0)),(H5*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,PARTMAS,6,0),0)),(H6*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,PARTMAS,6,0),0)))
```

As you can see the cells to look for are one row down every part of the sum. This makes me believe there should be a better way to formulate this.

Thanks in advance

The furmula now is :

```
0.001*SUM((H4*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,PARTMAS,6,0),0)),(H5*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,PARTMAS,6,0),0)),(H6*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,PARTMAS,6,0),0)))
```

Comment: Put the vlookup into the cells then use sumproduct()

Comment: Can you show sample data with expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

If you put into cell I4 the vlookup for B4 and so on for B5 and b6,

then

```
=SUMPRODUCT(H4:H6,I4:I6)*0.001
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a bit shorter with an array-type formula:

```
=0.001*SUMPRODUCT(H4:H6*(COUNTIF(Partmas,B4:B6)>0))
```